# Error in web application -

Tags: asp.net, .net, coding-style

When I try to run a report on my web application I get this error:

Server Error in '/Revenue' Application.

Input string was not in a correct format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

```
Line 219:        var ans = from a in analytics.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
Line 220:                  group a by a["LineTitle"] into g
Line 221:                  select new                  
Line 222:                  {
Line 223:                      Name = g.Key.ToString(),

[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +10691639
   System.Double.Parse(String s) +23
   Main_Report.<CountryAnalytics>b__2e(IGrouping`2 g) in d:\vistaweb\Revenue\MainReport.aspx.cs:221
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source) +4125469
   ASP.mainreport_aspx.__DataBind__control28(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\vistaweb\Revenue\MainReport.aspx:303
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +85
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +187
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +94
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) +136
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +484
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +63
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind() +54
   Main_Report.Page_LoadComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\vistaweb\Revenue\MainReport.aspx.cs:118
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e) +9631466
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +765
```

The code in the file looks like this:

```
   var ans = from a in analytics.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
              group a by a["LineTitle"] into g
              select new                  
              {
                  Name = g.Key.ToString(),
                  SalesPersonStats = g.Key.ToString().Contains(SP.FullName),
                  Value = g.FirstOrDefault()["LinaValue"].ToString(),
                  Percentage = g.FirstOrDefault()["LinePercent"].ToString(),
                  Change = Math.Round(double.Parse(g.FirstOrDefault()["LinaValue"].ToString()) - double.Parse(g.LastOrDefault()["LinaValue"].ToString()), 2)
              };
```

Any idea why it says input string waes not in a correct format 'select new' ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Probably, exception is thrown from double.Parse in this statement:

```
Change = Math.Round(double.Parse(g.FirstOrDefault()["LinaValue"].ToString()) - double.Parse(g.LastOrDefault()["LinaValue"].ToString()), 2)
```

Add .ToList() to the end of LINQ statement, so that query will be evaluated (& exception thrown) before report is being binded. There you have chances to debug the format.